# Render different views for tablets and mobiles react native

Tags: react-native

I want to change the ui based on device type like mobile,tablets and iPad. Is there any best practice to achieve this in react native.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. What did you try? What is the expected result? Can you show us some code? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

There are two options that you can consider:

1) Use a library like `react-native-device-info` to detect if the device is a tablet or a mobile phone. If you're intending to have completely separate features for tablets vs mobile devices, you could render specific components depending on the device type.

2) Write style sheets/ component styles to scale to any device size. You should be doing this anyway but if you are not wanting specific features for specific devices types, this is the correct way to do it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: I am displaying a master detail layout in which list will be displayed on the left side and on selecting on the list item i am  displaying the item details screen in rightside.

Comment: This is the layout for tabs and iPad. 
For mobiles i don't want to show the list on left side instead i want to display a arrow symbol which opens list from left side on clicking.

Comment: render () {
    if (this.state.portrait == true) {
      return (
        <View style={Styles.container}>
          {this.state.expand &&
            <ListComponent style={Styles.listComponent} />}
          <DrawerComponent expandList={this.expandList.bind (this)} />
          <DetailsComponent style={Styles.DetailsComponent} />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={Styles.container}>
          <ListComponent style={Styles.listComponent} />
          <DetailsComponent style={Styles.DetailsComponent} />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

Comment: currently i am using the above logic for orientation changes.Is it a good practice or 
  is there any better way to do it.